# How to find the first $5$ terms in Geometric Progression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometric-progressions

I am stuck on this question:

The sum of the first and the third terms of a Geometric Progression is $20$ and the sum of its first three terms is 26. Find the progression by writing the first $5$ terms.

I know these formula:
$$S_n= \frac{a(1-r^n)}{(1-r)}$$

where the $n$-th term is $ar^{n-1}$.

However I don't know how to find the first term $(a)$, the ratio $(r)$.

any help will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: $r$ is the common ratio, not the common difference.

Answer (score 2):

$$a+ar^2=20,\\a+ar+ar^2=26.$$

Obviously, $$ar=6$$

leading to

$$20a=a(a+ar^2)=a^2+6^2.$$

The solutions of this quadratic equation are

$$a=2,r=3,\\a=18,r=\frac13.$$

Then

$$2,6,18,54,162,\cdots$$ or
$$18,6,2,\frac23,\frac29,\cdots.$$

Answer (score 0):

from the Problem we have
$$a_1+a_3=20$$ and $$a_1+a_2+a_3=26$$ with $$a_2=a_1q$$ and $$a_3=a_1q^2$$ we get the System
$$a_1+a_1q^2=20$$ and $$a_1+a_1q+a_1q^2=26$$
can you solve this?
dividing both equations and assuming that $$a_1\ne 0$$ we get
$$\frac{1+q^2}{1+q+q^2}=\frac{10}{13}$$ from here we get
$$1+q^2=\frac{10}{13}(1+q+q^2)$$
can you solve this equation?

Comment: what does the q stand for?

Comment: $q$ is the Quotient of two numbers of this progression

Comment: uh no sorry, i have no idea how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a $ be the first term of the progression and $r $ be the common ratio. It is given that $$a + ar^2 =20\tag {1}$$ $$a+ar+ar^2 =26\tag {2}$$ $$(2)-(1) \implies ar =6 \tag {3}$$ Thus, substituting in $(1) $, we get, $$\frac {6}{r}+6r =20 \Rightarrow 6r^2-20r+6=0$$ $$\Rightarrow  (6r-2)(r-3)=0$$ $$\Rightarrow r =\frac {1}{3},3$$

Hope you can take it from here by solving for $a $ in $(3) $ and writing out the terms.

Answer (score -1):

continuing (I will write $a$ instead of $a_1$):

since $a+aq^2=20$ and $a+aq+aq^2=26$, you have $aq+20=26$, i.e. $aq=6$.

now $20=a+aq^2=a+aq\cdot q=a+6q$.

the system of equations $a+6q=20$ and $aq=6$ leads to $a+\frac{36}{a}=20$, what gives $a=2$ or $a=18$. Hence $q=3$ or $q=\frac{1}{3}$ respectively.